# Getting error when adding value to channels in parse.com Installation table in android?

Tags: android, database, string, parse-platform

I am trying to add value to channels in Installation table in `parse.com` but I am getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid channel name

I am trying to add the value which starts with a numeric value, but it gets insert when a value starts with **string**. How can I solve this issue?

```
ParseInstallation install = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
PushService.subscribe(getApplicationContext(), value, <currentClass>.class);
install.saveInBackground();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
ArrayList<String> channelsToAdd = new ArrayList<String>();
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().addAllUnique("channels", channelsToAdd);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(
            new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {    
                        //success
                    } else {
                        //error
                    }
                }
            });
```